# list index out of bounds (0)

Tags: delphi

i posted a question on Fixing an error in a method declaration in a form in Delphi but after getting it fixed another error popped up upon compiling  and its saying project project1.exe raised exception class EStringListError with message 'list index out of bounds(0)'.when i press continue its not working but when i press break its flashing on the code  `neraz:=true;`
this is my code below

```
Procedure Reload;
var
    i:integer;
begin
form1.ListBox1.Clear;
form1.ListBox2.Clear;
if neraz then
HD;
neraz:=true;//..................here
form1.Label3.Caption:='free: '+inttostr(vs*32)+' byte'+#10#13+'cluster size = 32 bytes';
  i:=TABLE[nk1].nach;
   KolP1:=0; KolP2:=0;
   while (FAT[i]<>1024)  do begin
      if TABLE[fat[i]].tip then begin
          form1.ListBox1.Items.Add('dir>'+TABLE[fat[i]].name);
          inc(kolP1);
      end
      else
          if TABLE[fat[i]].format='txt' then
                form1.ListBox1.Items.Add('f_text> '+TABLE[fat[i]].name+'.'+TABLE[fat[i]].format)
          else
                form1.ListBox1.Items.Add('f_bin> '+TABLE[fat[i]].name+'.'+TABLE[fat[i]].format);
      if (fat[i]<>0) then
      i:=fat[i];
   end;
   i:=TABLE[nk2].nach;
   while (FAT[i]<>1024)  do begin
      if TABLE[FAT[i]].tip then begin
          form1.ListBox2.Items.Add('dir>'+TABLE[fat[i]].name);
          inc(kolP2)
      end
      else
          if TABLE[fat[i]].format='txt' then
                form1.ListBox2.Items.Add('f_text> '+TABLE[fat[i]].name+'.'+TABLE[fat[i]].format)
          else
                form1.ListBox2.Items.Add('f_bin> '+TABLE[fat[i]].name+'.'+TABLE[fat[i]].format);
      if (fat[i]<>0) then
      i:=fat[i];
   end;
   vfail;
end;


procedure HD;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 49 do begin
    with form2.ListView1.Items[i] do begin
      SubItems[0] := TABLE[i].name;
      SubItems[1] := TABLE[i].format;
      if TABLE[i].tip then
        SubItems[2] := 'folder'
      else
        SubItems[2] := 'file';
      SubItems[3] := IntToStr(TABLE[i].nach);
      SubItems[4] := IntToStr(TABLE[i].razmer);
    end;
    form2.ListView2.Items[i].SubItems[0] := IntToStr(fat[i]);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Is your code really formatted like that? If so then you urgently need to learn how to indent your code correctly. Especially since you are mixing single statement and compound statement blocks. That makes life hard at the best of times but with no indentation discipline your code is unmaintainable.

Comment: if your code is not formatted like that, but it happened that you just pasted it this ugly, but you just don't care, then you cast doubt on your real interest that SO community helps you.

Comment: The for loop in HD assumes there are 50 items in both listviews. Are you sure that is the case? Either Listview being empty can trigger the exception, as well as either listview not/no longer having any subitems.

Comment: Out of bounds usually means you are trying to access a index outside of your for loop, or the index you are trying to access does not exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception class `EStringListError` raises the error List index out of bounds (0) when you try to access a member of a `TStrings` instance that is empty. The most likely candidate for that is the `SubItems` property of the list items.

You would appear to have fallen into quite a common trap. Although you have created columns for the list view, you also need to fill out the `SubItems` list for each list item. A simple solution is to modify `HD` like this:

```
with form2.ListView1.Items[i] do begin
  while SubItems.Count<5 do
    SubItems.Add('');
  SubItems[0] := ...
```

Although it may in fact be better to add the sub-items at the same time that you create the list items. But I'm not showing code for that since you didn't include the part of your program that populates the lists.